# .htaccess clean URL production, css appears to have not been applied

Tags: .htaccess

This is my first attemp at creating clean URLs using a .htaccess file.

My page is a simple, php generated page.

My page is http://www.dimiourgiasite.gr

On the top left corner of the page I have a link, pointing to http://www.dimiourgiasite.gr/arxiki

To redirect I use this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^arxiki$ index.php
RewriteRule ^arxiki/$ index.php
```

It is my understanding that weather I go to dimiourgiasite.gr/arxiki or dimiourgiasite.gr/arxiki/ I should be getting the same page. That is not the case.

Any explanations / things I am doing wrong?

Sorry I am not posting links and making you type the address, but since my rep is only 3, the site limits my amount of hyperlinks per post to 2.

Comment: What do you get instead of the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite and the page are both working fine.  The problem is that with a trailing slash, your browser tries to grab the *stylesheet* from `/arxiki/views/style.css` which doesn't exist.  Without the trailing slash, the stylesheet comes from `/views/style.css`.

If you change your stylesheet link in your source code to `/views/style.css` instead of `views/style.css`, the styles will be applied correctly.

You could probably have identified this from your Apache error logs as you would have seen a lot of "File not found" errors complaining about `/arxiki/views/style.css`.

You can also combine both your rewrite rules into one like this:

```
RewriteRule ^arxiki/?$ index.php
```

The question mark means "0 or 1 of the preceding character".

Comment: It is my understanding there are a number of different regex evaluations, depending on programming language. Which one does apache use in the .htaccess file?